# Looping through linked list C++ and returning the highest value of user input

Tags: c++, list, function, parameters, linked-list

The user inputs values of int age, and the function is supposed to accept parameters from a pointer to the head of the list,
and go through the linked list nodes and return the highest value of int age.

Heres my function; I keep getting random numbers as the output:

```
int findLargest (StudentCard *p) {
    int current = p->age;
    int next;

    StudentCard *temp = p;

    while(temp != NULL){
        if (p->age == NULL) {
            //The value at this node is obviously larger than a non-existent value
            return current;
        } else {
            //Recur to find the highest value from the rest of the LinkedList
            next = findLargest(p->next);
        }
        //Return the highest value between this node and the end of the list
        if (current > next) {
            return current;
        } else {
            return next;
        }
        temp=temp->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are missing a `return` statement at the end of your function.

Comment: `-1` or something to indicate nothing was found. Or even better make an output reference parameter for the found _largest_, and use `bool` as a return type.

Comment: can you show an example? I tried return -1; before the end of the func. still getting the same thing..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should `return -1` at the end of your function to inform that nothing was found.

Then secondly, you are sending the `p->next` as the parameter of `findLargest` function without checking `NULL` in following code:

```
//Recur to find the highest value from the rest of the LinkedList
next = findLargest(p->next);
```

And also, when you are using recursion function call, you don't need the `while(temp != NULL)` loop at all. You could replace the `while` with a `if` and remove the `temp = temp->next;` statement. Either recursion or iteration is enough for solving your problem.

Your `findLargest` function should be as following code:

```
int findLargest (StudentCard *p) 
{
    if (p != NULL)
    {
        int current = p->age;
        int next = findLargest(p->next);

        if (current > next) {
            return current;
        } 
        else {
            return next;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

For getting the oldest student node pointer, use following definition:

```
StudentCard * findLargestNode(StudentCard *p) 
{
    if (p != NULL)
    {
        int curAge = p->age;

        StudentCard *next = findLargestNode(p->next);

        if (next && (next->age > curAge)) {
            return next;
        } 
        else {
            return p;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

And for printing the oldest student ID, use the function as following

```
{
    StudentCard *pOld = findLargestNode(listHead); // `listHead` is HEAD node of your link-list
    if ( pOld )
        cout << pOld->id << endl;
}
```

Comment: I did all of that, it still doesn't work.... heres my full code: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=uz5egEja   my function is all the way at the bottom

Comment: case 6:// to find the oldest student on the list
    // findLargest(listHead);
    cout << findLargest << endl;

    break;

Comment: Still outputs random numbers

Comment: @hp456: In your this code `cout << findLargest << endl;`, Where is `findLargest` function argument? You are taking the function address value instead of it's return value. It should be  `cout << findLargest(listHead) << endl;`.

Comment: how about if i want the ID of the oldest student to output instead?

Comment: @hp456: If you want to get the ID of the oldest student, you've to redefine the `findLargest` function. I've added it in my answer.

Comment: error: cannot overload functions distinguished by return type alone

Comment: @hp456: Oh sorry. You've to rename the function and use the new name where needed.

Comment: Do i make the another new function ? with a new integer or just edit the findLargest part with something else ?

Comment: @hp456: Yes, you have to make a new function. I've updated it in my answer. Because you can't overload a function by changing the return type only.

Comment: Error 1 error C2360: initialization of 'pOld' is skipped by 'case' label, and Error 3 error C2361: initialization of 'pOld' is skipped by 'default' label are my new errors

Comment: For declaring a variable inside switch case, You've to use a `{ }` inside your `case 6:` as I've updated in my answer.

Comment: Thank you, it works. PS: StudentCard *next = findLargest(p->next); in the second piece of code should be StudentCard *next = findLargestNode(p->next); you may want to edit it for others

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing iteration with recursion, which is usually not a good idea.

(Your compiler should have warned about possibly not returning a value from the function. )

You're also possibly dereferencing a null pointer here:

```
int current = p->age;
```

and comparing the wrong thing here:

```
if (p->age == NULL)
```

(The fact that the program doesn't crash makes me suspect that you have an object with zero age somewhere, causing you to return that zero instead of recursing.)

If you read the loop carefully, you'll notice that it always returns a value on the first iteration, so `temp` is never advanced, and the `while` could be replaced with `if`.

You should rewrite the function to be either iterative or recursive.

An iterative solution would look like this:

```
int findLargest (StudentCard *p)
{
    int current = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
    while (p != NULL){
        if (p->age > current) {
            current = p->age;
        }
        p = p->next;
    }
    return current;
}
```

and a recursive solution would look like this:

```
int findLargest (StudentCard *p)
{
    if (p == NULL) {
        return std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
    }
    return std::max(p->age, findLargest(p->next));
}
```

Comment: Error 1 error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'std::numeric_limits<int>::_Ty (__cdecl *)(void) throw()' to 'int'

Comment: Error 2 IntelliSense: a value of type "int (__cdecl *)()" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "int"

Comment: @hp456 I forgot the brackets - it should be `min()`. Updated answer.

Comment: Still no luck. http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=1frbvtrB is my code, with the function you gave me all the way at the bottom. the function must execute from case 6